# Calculating number of entries of a page table

Tags: operating-system, paging

Consider the following :
In a system, if virtual address = 32 bits, physical address = 24 bits, and the page size is 8KB. 
Now we need to calculate the number of entries in the page table , my answer is as follows : 
Here the page size is 8kB meaning that the offset is 13 ( 2^13=8K) , so now we have the logical address is 32 bits meaning that the page offset bits are 32-13=19, so therefore the page table will have 2^19 entries . Is that right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be 2^32 / 2^13 = 2^19 entries indeed.